# Exception querying a Mocked Entity Framework Context

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, moq, xunit.net

When I Create an instance of Mock with MockBehavior.Strict I'm getting the error

An exception of type 'Moq.MockException' occurred in Moq.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: DbContext.Set() invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.

All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.

But I already made the setup for every table including that one:

```
        var mockContext = new Mock<JournalsDB>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Publications).Returns(mockPublicationSet.Object);
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Journals).Returns(mockJournalSet.Object);
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.AspNetUsers).Returns(mockUserSet.Object);
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.AspNetRoles).Returns(mockRoleSet.Object);
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.AspNetUserClaims).Returns(mockClaimSet.Object);
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.AspNetUserLogins).Returns(mockLoginSet.Object);
```

I suspect that the issue maybe is with my Repository Implementation or the DbContext Implementation:

```
        public class JournalRepository<DataObject, DataContext> :    IRepository<DataObject, DataContext>, IDisposable
 where DataObject : class
 where DataContext : DbContext
{
    #region Propiedades

    private readonly DataContext _ctx;
```

etc...

```
 public partial class JournalsDB : DbContext
 {
    public JournalsDB()
        : base("name=JournalsDB")
    {
    }

    public JournalsDB(string connectionName)
        : base(connectionName)
    {

    }
```

etc...

EDIT:

Without MockBehaviour.Strict I get the error Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source when querying any DbSet but the DbSets are correctly populated.

[image: Error consulting the DbSet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really think you're taking the wrong approach here, to be honest. Mocking `DbContext` is really painful, because that's a really wide interface. This is really a case of trying to dummy up an interface that you don't own. Mocking someone else's interface is always an invitation for trouble. In the case of `DbContext` you would really want to also mock the behavior of calls like `SaveChanges()`.

I would isolate the usage of `DbContext` behind a much smaller interface that is easier to mock. Then, you'll have two types of tests you want to write:

1. Unit test whatever uses the new interface. Those tests will be easier to write because you won't have to dummy up the `DbContext`
2. Test the class that *implements* the interface using a real database with real data in it. This way, you can test your data access layer in isolation.

For a more detailed explanation, see the answer I wrote here:  [Effort- FirstOrDefault returns null when Faking Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939215/effort-firstordefault-returns-null-when-faking-database/38939538#38939538)

Comment: I had a not so good repository pattern implementation. Right now I'm rewriting that code to avoid the dependency in the DbContext Object. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yep. If you mock interfaces that you own, then you can control whether or not they change their contract. But someone else's interfaces or objects, an upgrade with breaking changes in the API will also break your tests that mock their API in sometimes subtle and frustrating ways.

My general approach has always been to wrap external service classes in classes that I declare and control the interface for. In other words, I try and limit the surface area of the external dependency. This has almost universally led to more stable code bases for me.