# Effort- FirstOrDefault returns null when Faking Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, effort

I'm trying to create some unit tests for my project, after much digging around I found Effort, the idea is great, it mocks the database instead of the dealing with faking the DBContext which by the way is really hard to get it right when using a complex schema.

However I'm trying to get the Email of a user after I specifically added it to the in-memory database create by Effort, here is the code

```
MyContext contextx = new MyContext(Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient());

var client = new Client
{
    ClientId = 2,
    PersonId = 3,
    Person = new Person
    {
        PersonId = 3,
        EMail = "xxxxx@gmail.com"
    }
};
contextx.Client.Add(client); //<-- client got added, I checked it and is there

var email = contextx.Client.Select(c => c.Person.EMail).FirstOrDefault();
```

In the last line above I can't make it to return the email xxxx@gmail.com instead it always returns null.

Any ideas?

Comment: `contextx.SaveChanges();`

Comment: @Fabio yes,that fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answering Your Direct Question

For the specific question you asked, I would suggest two things:

1. Take a look at `contextx.Client.ToArray()` and see how many members you really have in that collection. It could be that the `Client` collection is actually empty, in which case you'll indeed get null. Or, it could be that the first element in the Client collection has a null value for `EMail`.
2. How does the behavior change if you call `contextx.SaveChanges()` before querying the `Client` collection on the DbContext? I'm curious to see if calling `SaveChanges` will cause the newly inserted value to exist in the collection. This really shouldn't be required, but there might be some strange interaction between Effort and the `DbContext`.

**EDIT:** `SaveChanges()` turns out to be the answer.

#### General Testing Suggestions

Since you tabbed this question with the "unit-testing" tag, I'll offer some general unit testing advice based on my ten years spent as a unit testing practitioner and coach. *Unit* testing is about testing various small parts of your application in isolation. Typically this means that unit tests only interact with a few classes at once. This also means that unit tests should not depend on external libraries or dependencies (such as the database). Conversely, an *integration* test exercises more parts of the system at once and may have external dependencies on things like databases.

While this may seem like a quibble over terminology, the terms are important for conveying the actual intent of your tests to other members of your team.

In this case, either you are really wanting to unit test some piece of functionality that happens to depend on DbContext, or you are attempting to test your data access layer. If you're trying to write an isolated unit test of something that depends on the DbContext directly, then you need to break the dependency on the DbContext. I'll explain this below in **Breaking the Dependency on DbContext** below. Otherwise, you're really trying to integration test your DbContext including how your entities are mapped. In this case, I've always found it best to isolate these tests and use a real (local) database. You probably want to use a locally installed database of the same variety you're using in production. Often, SqlExpress works just fine. Point your tests at an instance of the database that the tests can completely trash. Let your tests remove any existing data before running each test. Then, they can setup whatever data they need without concern that existing data will conflict.

#### Breaking the Dependency on DbContext

So then, how do you write good unit tests when your business logic depends on accessing `DbContext`? **You don't.**

In my applications that use Entity Framework for data persistence, I make sure access to the `DbContext` is contained within a separate data access project. Typically, I will create classes that implement the Repository pattern and those classes are allowed to take a dependency on `DbContext`. So, in this case, I would create a `ClientRepository` that implements an `IClientRepository` interface. The interface would look something like this:

```
public interface IClientRepository {

    Client GetClientByEMail(string email);

}
```

Then, any classes that need access to the method can be unit tested using a basic stub / mock / whatever. Nothing has to worry about mocking out `DbContext`. Your data access layer is contained, and you can test it thoroughly using a real database. For some suggestions on how to test your data access layer, see above.

As an added benefit, the implementation of this interface defines what it means to find a `Client` by email address in a single, unified place. The `IClientRepository` interface allows you to quickly answer the question, "How do we query for `Client` entities in our system?"

Taking a dependency on `DbContext` is roughly the same scale of a testing problem as allowing domain classes to take a dependency on the connection string and having ADO.Net code everywhere. It means that you have to create a real data store (even with a fake db) with real data in it. But, if you contain your access to the `DbContext` within a specific data access assembly, you'll find that your unit tests are much easier to write.

As far as project organization, I typically only allow my data access project to take a reference to Entity Framework. I'll have a separate Core project in which I define the entities. I'll also define the data access interfaces in the Core project. Then, the concrete interface implementations get put into the data access project. Most of the projects in your solution can then simply take a dependency on the Core project, and only the top level executable or web project really needs to depend on the data access project.

Comment: calling SaveChanges fixed it, about the repository pattern, I've gone down that route in other projects and it get's to a point where I have way too many functions in my repository class for minimal stuff, for this case I specifically didn't want to use repository pattern with UnitOfWork because of that problem, for every variation of a query then a new function needs to be created, IMO is too much of  a hassle doing it they way you propose but thanks though.

Comment: I understand. We all have our preferences. For the sake of others reading this, I'll elaborate on my reasoning. I prefer to test the data access in isolation because then I know it works. It's precisely for the reasons that you bring up that I prefer this isolation. I *want* to test each an every query to make sure things work correctly. Outside of the DAL, I want to be setup where I can easily stub out those results without setting up real entities.

Comment: @Fabio What are you talking about that I didn't answer the question? The top of my answer was `contextx.SaveChanges()`. See bullet point #2. The original poster even has a comment to such effect as the first comment on this answer. Please read the response more carefully before submitting your down vote.

Comment: From bullet point 2: _I'm curious to see if calling SaveChanges will cause the newly inserted value to exist in the collection. **This really shouldn't be required**, but there might be some strange interaction between Effort and the DbContext_ . I am apologize, but this seems more like a comment than answer. I am one hundred percent with you about breaking dependency to database layer.